# remainder term for a Taylor polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

The question asks:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=e^x$

(a) Find the $n$th order Taylor polynomial about x = 0, and the corresponding remainder term.

I can quite comfortably find the $n$th order Taylor polynomial, just by expanding the Taylor series and then finding the pattern to get the Taylor polynomial which is:

[image: taylor polynomial]

However I get stuck when trying to find the remainder term.
In my book it says the remainder term is equal to:

[image: formula for remainder term]

Could anyone help out?

The solution for the remainder term is:

[image: solution]

Comment: You need to watch this video: https://youtu.be/jiEaKYI0ATY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remainder of the Taylor expansion of a smooth function $f$ near $b$ is indeed $\dfrac{f^{(k+1)}(c)}{(k+1)!}(x-b)^{k+1}$, for some $c$ between $b$ and $x$. In particular, if $b=0$ and $f=\exp$, this will give you that the remainder is $\dfrac{e^c}{(k+1)!}x^{k+1}$, for some $c$ between $0$ and $x$.

Comment: Could you please show some working??

Comment: I cannot imagine what else could possibly be added to my answer.

Comment: I understand it now, just took me a while. Thank you.